# SVG with React via svgr failing

Tags: reactjs, svg

Having this in the webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      }
    ]
  },
```

And a simple import Component

```
import Globe from './Globe.svg'

(...)
<div>
  <Globe />
</div>
```

Results in the following error with a hard stop for the whole page render.

```
Warning: <data:image/svg+xml;base64,ZnVuY3Rpb24gX2V... (more here)0.=87…
...BkZWZhdWx0IFN2Z0NvbXBvbmVudDs= /> is using incorrect casing. 
Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

Comment: Have you figured out a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems known issue https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr/issues/83.

I would suggest include `url-loader`. https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/docs/webpack/#using-with-url-loader-or-file-loader

> In your webpack.config.js:
>
> ```
> {   test: /\.svg$/,   use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'], }
> ```
>
> In your code:
>
> ```
> import starUrl, { ReactComponent as Star } from './star.svg' 
> const App = () => (
>   <div>
>     <img src={starUrl} alt="star" />
>     <Star />
>   </div>
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled upon this one, too. When I try to use { ReactComponent as Star }, all I get is 'undefined' accompanied with an error: You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Can you put your file svg to codesanbox? So we can reproduce it.

Comment: Isn't `{ ReactComponent as Something }` specific to `create-react-app`? I have the same errors in a Next.js project.

Comment: No, it is just how `create-react-app` configured webpack